# How node.js resolves required folders using index.js without specifying folder path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, node-modules

I came across a pattern of importing folders in node.js/Javascript where only folder name is specified not folder path. **I'm not referring to packages from npm/yarn,** but rather to local folders. For example in file `a.js`:

```
import { someFunc } from 'helpers'
```

whereas the folder structure is:

```
src
  helpers
    someFunc.js
    index.js
  components
    a.js
```

Although I suspect that such way of importing in `a.js` is enabled by having an index.js file exporting `someFunc`, I couldn't find any documentation on such approach. Does Javascript recursively searches parent directories until it finds a folder with the name `helpers` containing index.js? Is this mechanism provided by Javasript or something else?

Comment: There is no such way where you can only refer folder name. Either that has to be npm package or you need to specify relative path to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK,** If you do not mention the absolute path of the file then node search in `node_modules`. Example:

```
const express = require('express'); // Would search in node_modules
const express = require('./express'); // Would search for express.js in current directory
```

Comment: I updated my question, I was not referring to npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that such pattern can be enabled by babel.js [module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) feature.